# dplyr - use case_when with several criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe called `data` which contains a column called `Sex`. In a survey that was conducted, this question offered two initial choices, "Male" and "Female" and the option "Other" which was open-end and people could write whatever they wanted.

For the sake of simplicity, I am trying to recode all other options to NA and keep only male and female. This was my attempt:

```
data %>%
   mutate(Sex = case_when((Sex != "Male" & Sex != "Female") ~ NA))
```

However, this resulted with a column with all NAs. I also tried the following, although I think it makes no sense:

```
data %>%
   mutate(Sex = case_when((Sex != "Male" | Sex != "Female") ~ NA))
```

And the result was same. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Unfortunately I can't post the data because it's confidential.

Comment: There is no need whatsoever to post confidential data when providing a small reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `TRUE` i.e. default condition to return the column itself, as by default it returns `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(Sex = case_when(Sex != "Male" & Sex != "Female"
               ~ NA_character_, 
         TRUE ~ Sex))
```

Or it can be also written with `%in%`

```
data %>%
    mutate(Sex = case_when(!Sex %in% c("Male", "Female") 
            ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ Sex))
```

Or instead of `case_when`. use `replace`

```
data %>%
   mutate(Sex = replace(Sex, Sex != "Male" & Sex != "Female", NA_character_))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! Just add the `_` after `NA_character` in the second option in your answer!